# Hive SQL:How do I compare multiple columns and select a value from one of them

Tags: sql, hive, min

In short I want to select the smallest date across multiple columns.

```
A                 B             C          D
2015-01-01      2015-01-05       Null     2013-01-01
```

from above I want to select the smallest date and put it in colunn E.
How do I do that - I will deploy it on 800M recs, so it would be nice with an elegant solution :)
Thanks..

Lasse

Answer (score 0):

The function you want is `least()`.  The problem is the `NULL` value. This might be sufficient:

```
select least(coalesce(A, '2099-12-31'),
             coalesce(B, '2099-12-31'),
             coalesce(C, '2099-12-31'),
             coalesce(D, '2099-12-31')
            )
```

To deal with all of the values being `NULL`:

```
select (case when coalesce(A, B, C, D) is not null
             then least(coalesce(A, '2099-12-31'),
                        coalesce(B, '2099-12-31'),
                        coalesce(C, '2099-12-31'),
                        coalesce(D, '2099-12-31')
                       )
        end)
```